# How to complete an ajax function before submitting a form

Tags: jquery, callback, form-submit

I need to take some actions which involve updating a database table when a user clicks on the form submit button. I want this action to complete before I now submit the form but it doesn't work yet. Here is the codes

```
// On form submission
$("#profile").submit(function() {
    submitForm(function(result) {
        return result;
    });
});

function submitForm(callback) {
    var dept;
    if (IsEmpty($("input[name=dept_id1]").val())) {
        dept = $("select[name=dept_id]").val();
        $.post("funcs.php", {'dept':dept, op:'select'}, function(d) {
            callback(true);
        });
    } else {
        dept = $("input[name=dept_id1]").val();
        $.post("funcs.php", {'dept':dept}, function(d) {
            callback(true);
        });
    }
}
```

If I prevent the form from submitting, the action will complete successfully but I'll have to manually go to the result page to see the changes. If I allow the form to submit, the changes won't take effect.

**The codes I pasted here allows the form to submit after the ajax function, but it doesn't make any changes on the server side.**
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I assume you're using an element like '<input type="submit">'  as the button which submits the form?

Comment: Yes, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a button rather than submit button in your form in this situation. If you're currently using, for example:

```
<form id="profile">    
Some form fields
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then consider instead doing:

```
<form id="profile">
Some form fields
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm(submitCallback);" />
</form>
```

This would prevent the form from automatically submitting when you click the button. You could actually submit the form in the callback function, for example:

```
function submitCallback() {
    $('#profile').submit();
}
```

Or something along those lines. Code not tested, but it should be something along these lines.

Edit: After doing that, you'd want to drop the eventhandler in your original code for $('#profile').submit ...otherwise you'd be running that ajax stuff twice.